# How to check equality of pairs

Tags: coq

I want to prove the following theorem on two pairs of type TR:

```
Definition s:= nat.

Definition d:= nat.

Definition c:= nat.

Definition p:= nat.

Inductive rt: Set :=

    |al : rt
    |bl : rt.

Definition TR: Set :=
   rt* s*d* c* p.

Implicit Types m n : TR.

Theorem eq_TR_dec : forall n m, {n = m} + {n <> m}.
```

For now, the proof of this theorem begins by intros n. destruct n. destruct m. But I cannot figure out the best tactic to prove this theorem. Any idea how should I prove this theorem? Thank you

Comment: Do you know about the tactics `decide equality`?

Comment: And another useful one: `repeat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, you can use `decide equality` which basically solve these goals (check the documentation [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/tactics.html#hevea_tactic186) to learn more).

In this case, just apply it as many times as needed and it works :

```
Theorem eq_TR_dec : forall n m, {n = m} + {n <> m}.
Proof.
  decide equality.
  - decide equality.
  - decide equality.
    * decide equality.
    * decide equality.
      + decide equality.
      + {
        decide equality.
        - decide equality.
        - decide equality.
        }
Qed.
```

or more simply using the [`repeat tactic`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/ltac.html#hevea_tactic215) (as also mentionned in eponier's comment), which basically applies (reccursively in the subgoal generated) the tactic you give it until it fails:

```
Theorem eq_TR_dec : forall n m, {n = m} + {n <> m}.
Proof.
  repeat decide equality.
Qed.
```

As we saw in the first case, here you only need to solve apply `decide equality` enough times, so `repeat` is particularly efficient !